# How to get images in app\assets\images in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and I am using Ruby version 1.9.3 and Rails version 3.0.0.

I want to get image in my project app\assets\images directory. How do I do that?

See below my code:-

```
<%= image_tag("images/vertax_logo1_03.png", :alt => "vertax24seven") %>
```

Above the code not given any error but image not display in my page.

please help me. How do I do that?

Comment: If your new to rails and not working on an existing app it might be best to get straight into Rails 4

Answer (score 4):

If you are storing the images in assets/images folder

```
<%= image_tag("vertax_logo1_03.png", :alt => "vertax24seven") %>
```

can show your image.

This [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path) will help you to customize your image path